# Error while using getVideoDurationInSeconds function from the “get-video-duration” library

Tags: electron

I’m trying to create a video player using electronjs. I couldn’t get the video duration directly using node.js so I had to use a library called **“get-video-duration”**.
But whenever I’m trying to use the **getVideoDurationInSeconds()** function, It’s throwing an error.

***Here Is The Error:***

> (node:12468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No duration
> found!
> at D:\Projects\Electronjs\video-player\node_modules\get-video-duration\dist\commonjs\index.js:83:27
> at step (D:\Projects\Electronjs\video-playerr\node_modules\get-video-duration\dist\commonjs\index.js:33:23)
> at Object.next (D:\Projects\Electronjs\video-player\node_modules\get-video-duration\dist\commonjs\index.js:14:53)
> at fulfilled (D:\Projects\Electronjs\video-player\node_modules\get-video-duration\dist\commonjs\index.js:5:58)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) (Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:12468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)

***Here Is The Code:***

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require("electron");
const { getVideoDurationInSeconds } = require("get-video-duration");
const path = require("path");

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

ipcMain.on("select-file", async (e, i) => {
  const { filePaths } = await dialog.showOpenDialog();
  let duration;

  getVideoDurationInSeconds(filePaths[0]).then((Duration) => {
    duration = Duration;
  });

  e.reply("select-file-reply", {
    url: filePaths,
    duration: duration,
  });
});
```